# Semantically designed data table with hierarchical rows sharing parent columns

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Sorry for the awkward title....

How could I display the following array as an html table that semantically (I'll worry about visually next) expresses that the items are all of the same data type while some members/rows are children of of other rows?

```
{Items:
      baseball bat : {
             price: 10
             discount: .20
             tax     : .08
       }
      chocolate cake : {
             price: 25
             discount: .10
             tax     : .05
       }
      robot parts : {
    head : {
        price: 100
        discount: .30
        tax     : .15
    }
    body : {
        price: 150
        discount: .25
        tax     : .125
    }
       }
      mustache wax : {
             price: 11
             discount: 0
             tax     : .5
       }
}
```

Ideally, this could be expressed with an html table so that a parser could produce the above array and a js library could easily populate the columns for the parent based on the children. It would also be ideal if the nesting were quasi-infinite.

This feels like a good use-case for the `headers` and `scope` attributes, along with `rowgroups`, but I want to be sure there isn't some aspect of the data table modle I'm missing or misunderstanding, since it seems like the price for a sub-item belongs to the list as a whole as well as to it's parent, but I'm not sure that would be expressed using only scope.

And any hints on a js/css framework like bootstrap that actually will properly parse such a table and make it look amazing are also welcome. But proper data modeling first!